# Why can I not use text() in a plot?

Tags: r, plot

I'm using a `plot()` in a super simple way:

```r
data <- matrix(c(9,13, 45, 47, 0, 1.5, 1.8, 1,"a", "b", "c", "d"), nrow = 4, ncol = 3)


plot(data[,1], data[,2], main='Ages', xlab='Age', ylab='Height')



index <- 0
for (age in data[,1]){
    index <- index + 1
print(age)
print(data[index,2])
    text(x=age, y=data[index,2], data[index, 3])

}
```

It draws the plot correctly, but not the text:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: In this case it is back to the original error. The index value is less than the lower xlim value.

Answer (score 0):

The x-range of the plotted data does not include 5.  You would need to extend the range to see the text. (Pretty common source of confusion for base plotting neophytes. I've fallen into it many times.  I think that maybe ggplot2 plotting routines might automagically expand the plotting dimensions.)

A further problem, already mentioned in the comments is that by including a character value in the matrix definition you changed all the digit values to character. Need `as.numeric` to revert to numeric class (or use a dataframe which would allow varying classes of columns.)

```
plot(data[,1], data[,2], main='Ages', xlab='Age', ylab='Height', xlim=c(0,50))

index <- 0
for (age in data[,1]){
    index <- index + 1
    print(age)
    print(data[index,2])
    text(x=as.numeric(age)+1, y=as.numeric(data[index,2]), data[index, 3])  
    }
```

Added an offset to the x coordinate for the letters:

[image]

Comment: This seems to work in the "hi" example, but it doesn't work when I use my algorythm, even though the x and y are always inside:                                                                              index <- 0
for (age in data[,1]){
 index <- index + 1
print(age)
print(data[index,2])
 text(x=age, y=data[index,2], data[index, 3])

}

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: Your code in the comment does not have any plot functions that set up a graphics device for output. The `text` function needs an open and current device. The `plot` and similar functions like histogram will do that, but `text` and `axis` will not. That sort of "subsidiary" function are expected to be used to lay over an "existing" plot and margin area.

Comment: Ok, but when I run `data <- matrix(c(9,13, 45, 47, 0, 1.5, 1.8, 1,"a", "b", "c", "d"), nrow = 4, ncol = 3)` before the for loop, it still won't work.

Comment: Again. No plot device was set up by that code. Furthermore you created an all character matrix because R matrices can only hold one atomic class of vectors. I didn't realize that the R `plot` function would be so kind by way of interpreting those character values as numeric.

Comment: Oops, wrong piece of code. I meant `plot(data[,1], data[,2], main='Ages', xlab='Age', ylab='Height', xlim=c(0,50), ylim=c(0,2))
`.

Comment: You were originally working with a character matrix and then you added a for- loop that adds 1 to a character. We really have no way to debug your code if you only add code fragments in comments.  Learn to post edits to you question body with [MCVE].

Comment: Ok, I changed the post. Does this explain it better?